# C# UWP bluetoothLE update count

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy, uwp-xaml

```
if (FindBluetoothLEDeviceDisplay(deviceInfo.Id) == null)
                        {
                            if (deviceInfo.Name != string.Empty)
                            {
                                // If device has a friendly name display it immediately.
                                KnownDevices.Add(new BluetoothLEDeviceDisplay(deviceInfo));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Add it to a list in case the name gets updated later. 
                                UnknownDevices.Add(deviceInfo);
                            }
                            rootPage.NotifyUser($"{KnownDevices.Count} devices found. Scanning completed.",
                            NotifyType.StatusMessage);
                        }
```

Hi. I am in need of help to update my rootPage. What I plan to do is to notifyuser by the number of devices found at the start. So everytime a ble devices is gone from the list. it updates the number of devices found and notify the user. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DeviceWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceWatcher) Class to enumerate devices dynamically, you can subscribe its [Added](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.devicewatcher.added), [Removed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.devicewatcher.removed) and [Updated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.devicewatcher.updated) so that the app receives notifications if devices are added, removed, or changed after the initial enumeration is complete.

Here is some simple code sample,

```
// Query for extra properties you want returned
string[] requestedProperties = { "System.Devices.Aep.DeviceAddress", "System.Devices.Aep.IsConnected" };

DeviceWatcher deviceWatcher =
            DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(
                    BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(false),
                    requestedProperties,
                    DeviceInformationKind.AssociationEndpoint);

// Register event handlers before starting the watcher.
// Added, Updated and Removed are required to get all nearby devices
deviceWatcher.Added += DeviceWatcher_Added;
deviceWatcher.Updated += DeviceWatcher_Updated;
deviceWatcher.Removed += DeviceWatcher_Removed;

// EnumerationCompleted and Stopped are optional to implement.
deviceWatcher.EnumerationCompleted += DeviceWatcher_EnumerationCompleted;
deviceWatcher.Stopped += DeviceWatcher_Stopped;

// Start the watcher.
deviceWatcher.Start();
```

More details, you can see the official sample [DeviceEnumerationAndPairing](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing).